# Material Datepicker with Cupertino UI

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I have Flutter app that is using Cupertino UI components. I want to show the the Material design date_picker instead of IOS style date picker. Is there any way I can do this?

In short I want to keep the same Material style date picker for both Android and IOS app. But whenever I use the date picker under Cupertino it throws an exception "**The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor**".

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3):

According to this [medium](https://medium.com/flutter-io/do-flutter-apps-dream-of-platform-aware-widgets-7d7ed7b4624d) post you can create an abstract class extending a `StatelessWidget` and using the `dart.io` package to determine the platform type. In your case you can test whether the underlying platform is `IOS` and use the material date picker using this :

```
  if(Platform.isIOS) {
    return createAndroidWidget(context);
  }
```

you can find the full code in the aforementioned post and it'll be easy to follow it.

Comment: I will try to implement it today. I have added more details to the question. Thank you for your time

Comment: Hi, I tried that but not working for me. Can you please put an example of how can we show Datepicker, dialog or even a showmodalbottomsheet under the Cuprtino?

Comment: Did you import the `material.dart` and called `showDatePicker()` function?