# Use cupertino widget with material Scaffold

Tags: flutter

Is possible to use some widgets from `flutter/cupertino.dart` inside a material app? (Using the `Scaffold`)

I want to render the `Switch` widget with the cupertino style instead the material.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976050/material-datepicker-with-cupertino-ui/54976599#54976599

Comment: Can you include some example of extending one Cupertino widget please?

Comment: This is an example from the medium post mentioned in the answer :                                            @Override 
 CupertinoNavigationBar createIosWidget(BuildContext context) => new CupertinoNavigationBar (
            leading: leading,
            middle: title,
);

Answer (score 5):

yes you can just import `flutter/cupertino.dart` and use it like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
Scaffold(
  body:Column(

     children:<Widget>[
       CupertinoSwitch(
         value: value,
         onChanged: (val){
         setState(() {
            value = val;
         });
        },
     )


     ]
  )
)
```